# "ufw status" becomes inactive without rebooting. is fail2ban service affecting ufw firewall?

Tags: server, iptables, firewall, ufw, apf

"ufw status" becomes inactive without rebooting. ("Service ufw status" remains active though, "iptables -L" also turns empty) I have setup ufw auto enabling upon reboot. But without rebooting the system the ufw status turns inactive after few hours within a day. everyday. I read about some apf related cronjob might affect the ufw status, but could not find any valuable information on that.

This is Ubuntu 16.04 version.

Thanks in advance.